# Need an execution context for combination of async and TPL code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, executioncontext

I'm looking for an execution context which plays nicely with `async/await` and with the TPL at the same time in the following way (expected behavior):

```
async Task<string> ReadContext(string slot)
{
    // Perform some async code
    ...
    return Context.Read(slot);
}
```

**(1) Playing nicely with `async/await`**

```
Context.Store("slot", "value");
await DoSomeAsync();
Assert.AreEqual("value", Context.Read("slot"));

Context.Store("slot", "value");
var value = await ReadContext("slot");
Assert.AreEqual("value", value);
```

**(2) Playing nicely with `Task.Run()`**

```
Context.Store("slot", "value");
var task = Task.Run(() => ReadContext("slot"));
Assert.IsNull(task.Result);
```

**(3) Playing nicely with an awaited `Task`**

```
Context.Store("slot", "value");
var value = await Task.Run(() => ReadContext("slot"));
Assert.AreEqual("value", value);
```

**(3)** is not essential but would be nice. I use `CallContext` now but it fails at **(2)** as the values stored in it are accessible even in manually ran tasks, even in those ran using `Task.Factory.StartNew(..., LongRunning)` which should enforce running the task on a separate thread.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: Doesn't look like a normal [Execution Ctx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx) to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand `Assert.IsNull` at **(2)** (which is the blocking wait on task.Result). Did you mean something like `Assert.IsNull(task.Result, "should be null")` ?

Comment: Basically, I need a place to store NHibernate sessions in ASP.NET application. `HttpContext` works fine (and respects `async/await`) if I'm inside a request context, but it is unavailable once I jump into manually ran tasks. Anyway, now I realized what I want is probably impossible since when I start a task manually, the environment does not know whether I'm gonna await it or not.

Comment: @Noseratio You're right, edited.

Comment: I'm surprised that `CallContext` is passed over to a pool thread via `Task.Run` like with **(2)**, are you sure? Anyway, now the requirements for **(2)** and **(3)** look mutually exclusive to me, if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: @Noseratio I was surprised as well. As to the mutual exclusivity of __(2)__ and __(3)__, you're probably right (unfortunately for me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your real question is in your comment:

> I need a place to store NHibernate sessions in ASP.NET application. HttpContext works fine (and respects async/await) if I'm inside a request context, but it is unavailable once I jump into manually ran tasks.

First off, you should be avoiding "manually run tasks" in an ASP.NET application at all; I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) on the subject.

Secondly, storing things in `HttpContext.Items` is sort of a hack. It can be useful in a handful of situations, but IMO managing NHibernate sessions is something that should be designed properly into your application. That means you should be passing around the session (or a service providing access to the session) either in your method calls or injected into each type that needs it.

So, I really think that a "context" like you're looking for is a wrong solution. Even if it were possible, which it is not.

As @Noseratio noted, requirements (2) and (3) cannot both be met. Either the code executing in the `Task.Run` has access or it does not; it can't be both.

As you've discovered, requirements (1) and (3) can be met by the logical call context (note to Googlers: this **only works** under .NET 4.5 and only if you store immutable data; details [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html)).

There is no easy way to satisfy (1) and (2) unless you manually remove the data (`FreeNamedDataSlot`) at the beginning of the code in `Task.Run`. I think there may be another solution but it would require custom awaitables at every await, which is completely cumbersome, brittle, and unmaintainable.

Comment: Stephen, I agree that passing the session from the top all the way down is the best solution. However, IMHO, it has a big disadvantage that you have to use this approach _everywhere_. You can't "relax" this requirement a little without having to come up with some kind of context.

Comment: As for not manually running tasks at all - this I have to do in cases where the operation takes long to process and the HTTP request cannot wait for it to finish (which I think is generally a good practice). Yes, I've read [your article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) :-)